# Get multiple checkbox values with onchange submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, get

I'm trying to get the checkbox values and keep the previous checked when submiting another with jquery onchange submit.

The problem is that only the last submited is maintained in the `$_GET['marca']` array. I'll be grateful if someone knows how to solve this.

```
if ( isset($_GET['marca']) ) {
  $_GET['marca'];
}
elseif ( empty($_GET['marca']) ) {
  $_GET['marca'] = null;
}

<form method="get">
 <input type="checkbox" id="amd" class="checkbox-filtro" name="marca" 
 value="amd">
 <label for="amd">AMD</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="evga" class="checkbox-filtro" name="marca" 
 value="evga">
 <label for="evga">EVGA</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="intel" class="checkbox-filtro" name="marca" 
 value="intel">
 <label for="intel">Intel</label>
</form>

$('.checkbox-filtro').on('change', function() {
  this.form.submit();
});
```

Comment: You have duplicate names.  Have you tried making them have unique names?

Comment: With your naming convention `$_GET['marca']` shouldn't be an array.

Comment: `name="marca"` should be `name="marca[]"` if you intend on using any or all of those. That or use radios instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your checkboxes should be `marca[]` to be used as array (as pointed by @FunkFortyNiner).

In the PHP, you could store in a variable to be sure that you have an array, even if nothing is sent.

Finally, in the HTML, you could use [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array) to check if the value is in your variable on not. If so, add the attribute `checked` to your checkbox.

```
<?php

// Check the presence of the index in $_GET and if it is an array to avoid errors with in_array().
$marca = isset($_GET['marca']) && is_array($_GET['marca']) 
       ? $_GET['marca'] : [];
?>

<form method="get">

 <input type="checkbox" id="amd" class="checkbox-filtro" name="marca[]" 
        value="amd" <?php echo in_array('amd', $marca) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
 <label for="amd">AMD</label>

 <input type="checkbox" id="evga" class="checkbox-filtro" name="marca[]" 
        value="evga" <?php echo in_array('evga', $marca) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
 <label for="evga">EVGA</label>

 <input type="checkbox" id="intel" class="checkbox-filtro" name="marca[]" 
        value="intel" <?php echo in_array('intel', $marca) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
 <label for="intel">Intel</label>

</form>
```

---

Your original PHP code have no effect:

```
if ( isset($_GET['marca']) ) {
  $_GET['marca']; // do nothing
}
elseif ( empty($_GET['marca']) ) {
  $_GET['marca'] = null; // change "empty" to null.
}
```

So, at this state, you cannot be sure that `$_GET['marca']` is defined or contains what you want.

Comment: That works like a charm, the only problem is that the brackets on name="marca[]" is encoding the query string like this marca%5B%5D=amd, is there a way to remove "%5B%5D" ?

Comment: @GabrielSouza Browsers display a nice URL. Did you mean when you copy/paste the URL?

Comment: When the form is submited that is how the url is displayed on Chrome and IE, on Firefox is displaying the brackets like this marca[]=amd

Comment: @GabrielSouza Oh, right! No. If you want to get a really nice URL, you have to use AJAX, or to POST your form instead of GET.